# jqgrid - sorting column breaks groups

Tags: sorting, jqgrid, grouping, break

I use jqgrid 4.6.0

When I click on a column header to sort rows, the initial grouping breaks.
datatype is JSON.

This is in colModel:

```
        {name:'name',width:150,resizable:true,title:false,sortable:true, editable:true},
        {name:'value',width:80,resizable:true,title:true,sorttype:'number'},
        {name:'col_type',width:80,resizable:false,title:false, editable:false}
```

And the grouping setting and additional settings:

```
loadonce:true,toppager:true,hidegrid:false,
grouping:true,gridview:true,rownumbers:false,
groupingView: {
    groupField : ['col_type'],
    groupText: ['<b> {0} </b>'],
    groupColumnShow : [false]
}
```

Obviously, I want the sorting of rows to be inside the groups.
Another question, is there any point setting the column to `hidden: true` in colModel? Since it's already defined in `groupingView`.

Comment: Could you verify whether the same problem exist in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.12.0? You need just to change temporary the URLs to jqGrid files to URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid which I develop since a year. It's compatible to jqGrid 4.6, but includes many bug fixes and enhancements.

Comment: I tested and it does work fine. So I guess it's a bug in jqGrid 4.6.0?
As for compability, it does work, but look somewhat different. Header row font size is much smaller, and row size as well. Maybe I should tweek css a bit. EDIT: I would say font size in smaller in general.

Comment: That brings me to another problem -  while sorting does works fine, the  initial group order, breaks while sorting..

Comment: It seems like free jqgrid sort the group names a well, which I dont want to happen. I want to preserve the original group order and just sort the rows. The demo which I used does not sort groups names as well, so I just want exacly this behaviour here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html. 
under Grouping -> hide grouping column

Comment: You should prepare the demo (for example as jsfiddle), which reproduce the problem. You can use [echo service](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) of JSFiddle `/echo/json/`.

Comment: I suppose that you have misunderstanding how grouping work. If the grid is grouped by `col_type` and sorted by `name` then one *has to* sort by `col_type, name`. It's required because one need **sort items inside of the group**.

Comment: I agree, it does mean to sort by col_type, name. The point is I want the sorting only to be inside the group, and to be preserve the original group order. Similar to the demo in my comment, the groups test1, test2, test3 - does not change their original order when you sort ascending or descending.

Comment: I think that one can go forward only if you create the demo which reproduce the problem. You should describe step by step to reproduce the problem with description of the expected results and the results which one see instead.

Comment: Ok. So I've created this demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/uz7Ltbjk/3/ . Using the free jqgrid. I've also used the echo/json option. As you can see, while sorting any column, the groups order changes. I want to retain the original order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained you already in the comment that the data returned from the server have to be sorted by `groupingView.groupField` (the field `col_type` in your case). On the other side you had the data

```js
var data = {"rows":[
        {"col_type":"group1",...},
        {"col_type":"group1",...},
        {"col_type":"aaa",...},
        {"col_type":"group3",...},
        {"col_type":"group3",...},
        {"col_type":"group4",...},
        {"col_type":"group4",...}
    ]};
```

where `"aaa"` group have the wrong order. It is possible that jqGrid hold your custom order, but you have to inform it about it. For example you can use `sorttype` defined as function or to use `sortfunc` callback function. For example, you can extend your input data to the following

```js
var data = {"rows":[
        {"col_type":"group1","col_type_order":1,...},
        {"col_type":"group1","col_type_order":1,...},
        {"col_type":"aaa","col_type_order":2,...},
        {"col_type":"group3","col_type_order":3,...},
        {"col_type":"group3","col_type_order":3,...},
        {"col_type":"group4","col_type_order":4,...},
        {"col_type":"group4","col_type_order":4,...}
    ]};
```

and to use `col_type` column as

```js
{
    name: 'col_type', width:80, resizable:false, title:false,
    sorttype: function (value, item) {
        return item.col_type_order;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:** See the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/uz7Ltbjk/7/. If you use old jqGrid and you loads the data from the server in combination with `loadonce: true` then you have to add hidden column `col_type_order`. If you use free jqGrid then you can use `additionalProperties`. The simlest form which you can use is the following:

```
additionalProperties: ["col_type_order"]
```

It informs jqGrid to read **additional properties (fields)** from the source data and place the information inside of local data saved in `data` parameter. In the way you can extend the local items with *any* additional information, which you can use later during sorting for example. By the way, one can have *any type* of the values of additional properties. For example it could be object or array. Such feature could be helpful for master/details grid or subgrids. One can load all required information at once and then use it.

Comment: I see. That's what I meant, I only want to sort the data inside the groups. When you define sorttype callback function for a grouped column (col_type), is that mean jqgrid will automatically sort like: [col_type callback function value] , [column selected by the user] ?  
Second, is there any way to group data without defining the groups in the data? As you can see my column is hidden. And I think I need to create another hidden column, for col_type_order?

Comment: Since it happened to me that jqgrid wont save data that isn't defined in colModel, when datatype is json.

Comment: I dont understand the sorttype function, item is simply the column data (string), not an object...

Comment: @user3599803: Sorry, I was busy during writing the answer to you. Now I'm back and can fix the code: https://jsfiddle.net/uz7Ltbjk/7/

Comment: @user3599803: Some more examples, which demonstrates `additionalProperties` you can find below: [demo1](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/sortByAdditionalProperties.htm), [demo2](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/forceClientSorting.htm), [demo3](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalProperties.htm), [demo4](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog.htm), [demo5](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog1.htm). See [the input data](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/sortfunc.json).